# How do I use high-order unicode characters in java?

Tags: java, unicode

How do I use unicode characters in Java, like the [Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter E](http://unicode-table.com/de/1F174/)? Using `"\u1F174"` doesn't work as the `\u` escape only accepts 4 hex-digits.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify it as a surrogate pair - two UTF-16 code units.

For example, if you copy and paste the character into my [Unicode explorer](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer) you can see that U+1F174 is represented in UTF-16 code units as U+D83C U+DD74. (You can work this out manually, of course.) So you could write it in a Java string literal as:

```
String text = "\uD83C\uDD74";
```

Other options include:

```
String text = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x1f174).toString();
String text = new String(new int[] { 0x1f174 }, 0, 1);
char[] chars = Character.toChars(0x1f174);
```

Comment: There is `Character.toChars()`

Answer (score 1):

```
"\uD83C\uDD74"
```

Or indeed

""

Because Java characters represent UTF-16 units rather than actual Unicode characters, you need to represent it as a string, that will have the two UTF-16 surrogates.